# Output of List@@func

Tags: list-manipulation

Hello I am trying to separate a function and get a list

> f[x_, y_] := Sin[x]+Exp[Cos[x]];
>      u = List @@ f[x, y]

Output is what I want and that is

> {E^Cos[x], Sin[x]}

If `f[x_,y_]:= Sin[x+y]`  the output is `{x + y}`. I wanted output to be `{Sin[x+y]}`. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you

Erdem

Comment: Evaluate `List @@ f //Trace` to see what is happening.  Also note `f` is not defining a function in either of the examples in your post.

Comment: Thanks, the solution is there. I just need to find the way to extract it.

Comment: You need to say more about the scope of the solution you are looking for.  The `@@` notation (for `Apply`) replaces the head of the expression.  In the first example, you replace a head of `Plus`, and apparently you want to replace the head.  In the second, you replace a head of `Sin`, but apparently you do not want to replace the head.  So, what is your actual goal, generally stated?

Comment: I want to able to separate the function for summations and subtractions. Like Sin[x+y]-1+ Sin[x] Exp[Cos[z]]  to {Sin[x+y],-1,Sin[x] Exp[Cos[z]]}

Comment: As @Alan explained, `List@@` replaces the head of the expression by List, which is fine if the head is, for instance `Plus`.  In the second example, the head is `Sin`, so use  `{f[x, y]}` instead to obtain `{Sin[x+y]}`.  Use `FullForm` to see the internal structure of an expression, but be prepared for a lot of output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still a bit unclear, but apparently you want to split an expression into a list of terms.  You could try this:

```
terms[expr_] := If[Head@expr === Plus, Level[expr, 1], {expr}]
```

Comment: I did not want to be too wordy. I am trying to check if the function is made of "subfunctions" that are separated by + or -. This will allow me to treat each "subfunction" separately and hoping to gain some computation time. And it looks like what you wrote is working.